# Insert Multiple Rows to Database LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-5

I have a foreach loop that iterates through a list of type `List<NewItem>`, creates a new instance of `NewItem`, sets its properties, then `Add()`s the item to the context to be inserted upon the execution of `SaveChanges()`:

```cs
foreach (var newItem in newItems)
{
    NewItem item = new NewItem 
    {
        User = newItem.User,
        Itemno = newItem.Itemno
    };

    db.NewItem.Add(item);

}

try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'NewItem' because it has a
>   DefiningQuery and no element exists in the element to support the
>   current operation.

Why isn't the `Add()` method actually adding anything to my db context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the target database table doesn't have a primary key, add one.